# FF Connection settings not remembered on new browser session

Tags: firefox

Every time I open up a FF browser, I have to go to Tools --> Advanced-->Settings and change the proxy setting to No Proxy.
Why FF does not remember the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. You have a [user.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file) override for network.proxy.type that resets it every time you restart.
2. Your Firefox is configured to use the system preference service.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can fix this

Comment: You can look in `about:config` for `config.use_system_prefs`; if this is true then you may need to set it to false. As for user.js, you need to read the linked page to find out how to edit it.